# Does the Java compiler search not give an unreachable statement error just because a break exists in a loop?

Tags: java, loops, compilation, break

This does not compile, giving an `unreachable statement` error:

```
  while(true)
  {
  }
  return null;
```

while this does not have any compilation issues though we know that it is equivalent to the snippet above:

```
  while(true)
  {
   if(4>5)
       break;
  }
  return null;
```

Does the compiler simply search for a break statement and think that there's some way that the loop *may* terminate and so does not worry about it?

Answer (score -1):

The compiler does not evaluate expressions within conditional statements. Even if you write:

```
while (true) {
    if (false) {
        break;
    }
}
```

it would not be detected as an infinite loop.

Comment: Of course it evaluates them. The example in the question and yours simply introduce some dead code because of the constant expression in the condition.